# Is there a way to use environment variables in a regular JS file that is inside a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I'm using the Spotify API to for my project and one of the variables I need to use is clientId. I don't want other people to have access to my client id, so I placed the variable in a .env file and added *.env into my .gitignore file. However when I try to access that variable in my script.js file, I keep getting "Uncaught Error: process is not defined".

At first, I tried to download and install packages like react-dotenv, dot-env, react-error-overlay@6.0.9. Then, I tried to delete my node_modules folder and package-lock.json, cleaned my cache with "npm cache clean --force", and "npm install" to reinstall the previously deleted files.

All I wanted to do was to keep my client id hidden yet accessible via .env file.

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` you can do that, but you have to add `REACT_` to the beginning of your variable. But not that it will still be accessible by the user. You can't hide anything from the user on the client side

Comment: `I don't want other people to have access to my client id,`   If it's server side, then nobody will.  If it's client side, then no matter what you do, there is no way to hide it totally.

Comment: To add to Konrad's comment, you cannot access system environmental variables from your browser. The only way to hide credentials is to provide an API that can handle authentication to limit access to your client ID.

Comment: To complement other comments:  `process` does not exist in browsers.  Tools/frameworks provide artificial support for it.  Most tools will replace instances of this variable with hardcoded values, which brings us to Keith's comment:  If it's a secret, don't put it in the client.  What you could do is ask the user of the web application to type in the client ID.